# Woocommerce remove view cart on checkout page

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

I need to remove the "Do you need to review your cart? - View Cart" section on the checkout page if the order total is zero.

[image]

I am relatively unfamiliar with customising the checkout page with this condition in place. How would I structure the woocommerce_before_checkout_form hook to do this from my functions.php

```
global $woocommerce;
$order = new WC_Order($order_id);
$total = $order->get_total(); //Get the total price of the order.
```